# git showの結果を表示するのに利用されるlessにoptionを渡したい

Tags: git

特に設定をしない状態で
`git show branch_name:filename`
を実行したら、`less`を使って結果が表示されました

この`less`に行番号を表示させる -N オプションを渡すには、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GIT_PAGER="less -N" git show`で可能です．

gitで使用されるpagerは環境変数の`$GIT_PAGER`がまず参照され，次に設定の`core.pager`が参照され，その次に環境変数の`$PAGER`，最後にコンパイル時に設定されたデフォルトのpager（大抵は`less`）が参照されます．
詳しくは`man git-config`の`core.pager`を参照してください．

永続的に設定を変更したい場合は`git config --global --add core.pager "less -N"`で設定を追加します．
この設定を消去したい場合は`.gitconfig`を編集します．